# C++ access to QML component properties without creating component instances

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Consider the following QML example component defined in Test.qml

```
Item {
    readonly property string name: "Test Component"
}
```

and I'm loading the component from C++

```
QQmlComponent comp(&engine, QUrl("file:/path/to/Test.qml"));
```

Is there any way to access the read only property `name` without creating an instance by calling `comp.create(...)`?  I'm asking this because I want to use QML components to realize dynamic plugins. Each plugin should represent a project dependent interface. These "plugin" QML Files will be contained in a single folder and should be presented as a listing of the plugin/component names. The user should than be able to select which one of the plugins should be used (and instantiated by the application).

Since each "plugin" will also affect how the underlying C++ model is built and only one "plugin" should be instantiated at the same time, creating an instance of each just to get the name would introduce a significant overhead which I'm trying to avoid.

Unfortunately the `property(...)` method of `QQmlComponent` only refers to the component object but not to the properties of the underlying QML component. Is there any way to read default/read only properties without creating an instance?

Suggestions for alternative solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: if you do not create an instance of the component it is just a file, so an option is to parse the file :(

Comment: Component is a definition of QML item. It has no properties since that isn't instance of the component.

Comment: To expand on @eyllanesc's suggestion, I would put a comment as the first line of the file, containing the name (and maybe even a description) with a specific enough syntax to verify that it is indeed one of your plug-ins. Then you can scan the files, presenting the user with what you find.

Comment: @mark That's basically what I'm doing now. But I decided to rename the `name` property to something more specific and I parse the property using a regular expression. It works quite nice in combination with a ListModel implemented in C++ and a QML Loader Component.